# Packets out of order

Tags: php

I'm trying to connect to an external database with php and I'm getting the "Packets out of order." error. I searched for it and I already changed the "max_allowed_packet" by query and by my.cnf, and both of which did not solve the problem.

> Warning: Packets out of order. Expected 0 received 45. Packet
>   size=4739923 in
>
> Warning: mysqli_connect(): MySQL server has gone away in  Warning:
>   mysqli_connect(): Error while reading greeting packet. PID=12844 in
>
> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2006): MySQL server has gone away in
>   Unable to connect to database! Please try again later.

Comment: How much data are you sending in your query? This has happened only once to me when I was uploading a full text of a book.

Comment: I'm not sending any data, I'm just trying to connect.

Comment: what versions of php / mysql are you using?

Comment: Version of php is 7.2.0 and version of  mysql is 5.7.26